# I Want to update some fields of database record in Django. How can Implement it Clean?

Tags: django-models

I have a Django model like below.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

so i want update it by a request that include some data. maybe all of filed has been modified or one field. say to me how can i implant it more efficient as it best.

i know about built-in function as `filter(...).update()` or `get()` then update and `save()` it. i want a generic way for write these clean as well.